# License Agreement Interface in WIX Setup Project

Tags: wix, licensing

As i am trying to build a customized Wix Setup project i need to include a license agreement interface. using WixUiExtension I can do it easily with this code

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="sample.rtf" />
```

But how can i get this .rtf file in my customized .wxs form without using WixUiExtension ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you'd like to achieve... Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define it like this inside your `UI` tags:

```
            <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
                <Text SourceFile="sample.rtf" />
            </Control>
```